# Display corresponding parallel array value to html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I currently have two arrays, nameArray and markArray which are added to when users input their name and mark. I want to display all names and marks at the click of a button but have what mark belongs to who obvious. My attempts are below creating displayInfo but whenever I try to output it to HTML it only shows the last one in each array.

````
    if (Array.isArray(nameArray) && nameArray.length) {

        console.log("display all working");
       // var displayName = nameArray.toString();
        // var displayMark = markArray.toString();

        for(let i=0; i < nameArray.length; i++){

            var displayInfo = "";

            //var displayInfo = nameArray[i] + "<br/>" + markArray[i];
            //console.log(displayInfo)
            //document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = displayInfo;

            displayInfo += nameArray[i] + "<br/>" + markArray[i] + "";

        }

            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = displayInfo

    }else{

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "No result's have been entered! Please enter results before display them!"
    }


} ```
````

```
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var mark = document.getElementById("mark").value;

if(name == "" || mark == ""){

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "An input field is empty please try again."

}else{

nameArray.push(name);
markArray.push(mark);

console.log(nameArray);

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = name + "'s " + "results have been added to the system!"

}
```

}```

The output should look something like John-4 Jack-6, just any way in which it is clear whos result it is.

Comment: Show us what your arrays look like and what your expected output looks like, that'll make it easier for us to help

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Array.isArray(nameArray) && nameArray.length) {

    console.log("display all working");
    var displayInfo = [];
   // var displayName = nameArray.toString();
    // var displayMark = markArray.toString();

    for(let i=0; i < nameArray.length; i++){


        //var displayInfo = nameArray[i] + "<br/>" + markArray[i];
        //console.log(displayInfo)
        //document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = displayInfo;

        displayInfo.push(nameArray[i] + "<br/>" + markArray[i] + "");

    }
       displayInfo.forEach(single => {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = single; 
       })



}else{

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "No result's have been entered! Please enter results before display them!"
}
```

You are overwriting your variable inside your loop until the loop ends, which is why you get the last element of the array. Try my code.

Comment: I updated the code and its still doing the same, I have updated the code as well.